# Vim <C-R><C-W> ignore current content of the line

Tags: vim

I have this script to search for the word under cursor in the current project:

```
nnoremap <leader>K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>
```

It works just fine except when the word starts with `b`.

This is due to `<C-R><C-W>` only completing the remaining of the word. For example, if I'm searching for "branch", my pattern gets something like this:

```
\branch\b
```

Which is equivalent to search for the work "ranch".

Any thoughts on how to figure this out?

Comment: you can use `-w` option to tell `grep` to search only for words.. that way you don't need to use `\b` and there is `-x` option if you want to match only whole lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `nnoremap <leader>K :execute 'grep! "\b"'.expand("<cword>").'"\b"'<CR>:cw<CR>`.

`<cword>` will expand to the current word under the cursor, as `:help :<cword>` explains, along with others:

```
<cword>    is replaced with the word under the cursor (like |star|)
<cWORD>    is replaced with the WORD under the cursor (see |WORD|)
<cfile>    is replaced with the path name under the cursor (like what|gf| uses)
```

[Check the help for more info](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:%3Ccword%3E).

Comment: This one works for me, I just had to do one change: `nnoremap <leader>K :execute 'grep! "\b"'.expand("<cword>").'"\b"'<CR>:cw<CR>`

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad. I was in a bit of a hurry and only tested with `:echo`. I'll edit to include your line.